# PHP: Find a value within a string and use that position to split the string into two

Tags: php, string, split

1. I need to find `<?target?>` withing a (dynamic) string (`$string`)
2. Take everything before `<?target?>` and assign it to `$a`
3. Take everything after `<?target?>` and assign it to `$b`
4. In my case, I only have one instance of `<?target?>` (But is good to have options =)

Since I have a hard time to explain what I am trying to do, I'll give you this pesudo code example:

```
$string = 
"Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus 
<?target?>
et netus et malesuada 
fames ac turpis 
egestas.";

FinctionToFindAndSplit ( '<?target?>' );
   $a = 
   "Pellentesque habitant 
   morbi tristique senectus";

   $b =
   "et netus et malesuada 
   fames ac turpis 
   egestas.";
```

Comment: have you considered using strpos ? http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple [explode()](http://php.net/EXPLODE) should work:

```
list($a, $b) = explode('<?target?>', $string);
```

Depending on what you want to do if multiple `<?target?>` are found you can use as is to discard what is after the others or use the third argument `2` to limit the explode and what is returned.

Comment: I like it that it is not in an array =) All in one line, simple and easy =)

Comment: Doh! At least you caught it.

Comment: @Omar `explode()` will return an array (or false) no matter to what you assign it to

Comment: `limit()` is good for me, since I only have one instance. However, `$arr = explode()` is good for those who need more than one instance like @rizier123 said

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by your delimiter. Also note that I limited the output to 2 elements! So if you have multiple delimiters in the string only the first one gets used and the other ones just ignored.

```
<?php

    $arr = explode("<?target?>", $string, 2);
    $a = $arr[0];
    $b = $arr[1];

?>
```

Comment: Nice! the array make it easy to just go `unset($arr)` if needed =) No need for more variables and use of more memory =)

Comment: It also allows to find more than one instance =)